# Mongo document to array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, toarray

I'm getting a document from MongoDB in Meteor like this:

```
Template.SubTasks.helpers ({
   subelement: function (){


      var sublen = TodosCol.find(this);
      // var sublen2 = ????

      return sublen2;
  }


});
```

It works great, sublen returns as object. But when I'm, trying to convert it to array (for example like:

`var sublen2 = sublen.toArray();`

or

`var sublen = TodosCol.find(this).toArray();`

or the whole collection (without 'this'), it doesn't work and I get an "undefined is not a function" error in chrome console.

I also tried

`var sublen2 = sublen.propertyName;`

since it's an object, with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm trying to iterate over values stored in array in a mongo document. I want to output them for example as separate div's. It's a simple task list. Tasks are iterating just great, but I'm trying to output subtasks assigned to a specific task. Subtasks are stored in the same document as their 'parent tasks' as an array of strings.

Template:

```
<template name='SubTasks'>
    <div class='sub-output {{_id}}'>
        {{#each subelement}}
            <div class='sub-task {{_id}}'>
                {{subtask}}
             </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by converting it into an array?share you html code so that we can clearly understand what you are upto..

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over values stored in array in a mongo document. I want to output them for example as separate div's. It's a simple task list. Tasks are iterating just great, but I'm trying to output subtasks assigned to a specific task. Subtasks are stored in the same document as their 'parent tasks' as an array of strings. Temolate: <template name='SubTasks'>
    <div class='sub-output {{_id}}'>
        {{#each subelement}}
            <div class='sub-task {{_id}}'>
                {{subtask}}
             </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

Comment: `subelement` is an array, right? in your html you can use `{{#each subelement`}} {{this}} {{/each}}`. you don't have to create an another helper for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TodosCol` is a collection, then its `.find()` method returns a Cursor - http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find. The cursor can be used to iterate through the results efficiently and reactively using `{{each}}`.

As the documentation explains, if you want the results of the `find()` call, you need to call `.fetch()` - learn more at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that javascript objects do not have a `toArray()` method.  I can't offer much help without more specifics.  Namely, what exactly do you want the array to contain?  Objects contain key value pairs, also known as properties.  You should log the object to the console when you first receive it and see what parts of the object you want to comprise your array.

If, for example, you want an array of keys/properties on the object, you might try [`sublen.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an array of the string names of each property (keys) on the object.

Perhaps you want an array that is already stored in the object as the value to some key.  By logging the object, you can find this key/property and access it via dot notation: `sublen.<property-name>`

go here to see what sorts of methods the js Object has on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I tried both .keys() and .<property-name> before, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a MongoDB Collection and inside that collection you have a key called `subtasks` which has an array.

```
Template.tasks.helpers({
  tasks:function(){
    return Tasks.find({}).fetch();
  }
});
```

Then in your HTML template.

```
<template name="tasks">
  {{#each tasks}}
    <div id ="{{_id}}">
        <p>{{title}}</p>
        <ul>
            {{#each subtasks}}
                <li>
                    <p>{{this}}</p> 
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```